# Need clarity on issue with factory_girl_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I want to test if the model has a valid factory. I was getting undefined method error when I used `create`, but it worked when I used `FactoryGirl.create`. Why is that.

Here is how the code looked like:

```
spec/models/contact_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Contact, type: :model do

  it "should be a valid factory" do
    contact = create(:contact)
    expect(contact).to be_valid
  end
end

spec/factories/contact.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do
    full_name     { Faker::Name.name }
    email         { Faker::Internet.email }
    phone_number  { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
    address       { Faker::Address.street_address }
  end
end
```

WhenI changed the spec to what I have below, I did not get the error

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Contact, type: :model do

  it "should be a valid factory" do
    contact = create(:contact)
    expect(contact).to be_valid
  end
end
```

Why is like that?

Answer (score 0):

See the getting started doc.  You need to do

```
 # RSpec
 # spec/support/factory_girl.rb
 RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
 end
```

If you don't then all of your calls to factory girl need to be prefixed with FactoryGirl

Comment: I actually have that added.

Comment: And you still need to prefix your methods? Does your rails_helper / rspec_helper source all files in spec/support ? Or did you add it to the main rspec_support file?

Comment: Oh that was the issue. I had not uncommented the line to source all files in spec/support. Thanks.